# Why it got extremely slow?

Tags: windows-7, edit, virtual-machine, rubymine

I've been working on RoR apps using RubyMine in Ubuntu within a Virtual Machine in Windows 7
Well .. every thing went fine for a long time ..
But newly, I've been noticing that editing any file would take very long time ( over 15 seconds )

Just when I try to type any thing .. it will hang for too long seconds ..

Any idea ? what could be wrong ? how can I reset RubyMine ?

**EDIT**

Ubuntu works fine inside vm, I can do other tasks with no delay, so VM process is not hanged, what hangs when I try to edit a file inside RubyMine is RubyMine it self.

Thanks

Comment: Did you look into your taskmanager in your vm? Maybe a process hangs.

Comment: Ubuntu works fine inside vm, I can do other tasks with no delay, so the process is not hanged, but it only hangs when I try to edit a file inside RubyMine (hangs inside RubyMine only)

Comment: See http://devnet.jetbrains.net/docs/DOC-1144.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did is re-install RubyMine on a different location, and every thing is fine again ..